# Python3: Replacing fields using .format() "{1:>2}"

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting

Just a quick one really, I am learning Python3 at the moment and saw this `{1:>2}` used for a replacement field. I was wondering if someone might be able to explain what it is doing here:

```
for i in range(2, 13):
    for j in range(1, 13):
        print("{1:>2} times {0} is {2}".format(i, j, i * j))
    print("=" * 20)
```

Is it essentially stating that i>j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:>2` is used for adding padding to the left side

```
print("{1:>2} times {0} is {2}".format(i, j, i * j))
```

Your message is:

```
{1:>2} times {0} is {2}".format(i, j, i * j)
```

The indexes are as follows:

```
0 = i
1 = j
2 = i * j
```

If the statement was:

```
{1} times {0} is {2}".format(i, j, i * j)
```

it would evaluate to

```
j times i is i * j
```

the `:>2` is what's adding the padding -- notice your print are all nicely formatted:

```
====================
 9 times 4 is 36
10 times 4 is 40
```

as opposed to this:

```
====================
9 times 12 is 108
10 times 12 is 120
```

Comment: Yup, I see that now. Makes sense, thanks very much!
This link also shows some examples:
https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align